# Edit JSON file with a use of AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, post

I tried to do that when I'm pressing the turn on button it calls the turnon() function which opens the JSON file named light.json and writes there {"light" : "on"} but it doesn't work for me and I don't know why. Can anybody help me?

```
    <?php  
$light = $_GET['light'];
$file = fopen("light.json", "w") or die("can't open file");
if($light == "on") {  
  fwrite($file, '{"light": "on"}');
} 
else if ($light == "off") {  
  fwrite($file, '{"light": "off"}');
}
?>

<html>  
  <head>      
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>LED for ESP8266</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

        <form>
            <input type="button" id="StartButton" value="Turn On" onClick="turnOn()">
        </form>
        <!--<button onclick="turnOn()">Turn On</button>
        <button onclick="turnOff()">Turn Off</button>-->

        <div class="light-status well" style="margin-top: 5px; text-align:center">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function turnOn() {

                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "http://192.168.1.108/test/light.json",
                    data: {"light": "on"},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean? Do you get errors? If so what errors?

Comment: `url: "http://192.168.1.108/test/light.json"` - you can not just post data "to" the URL of a JSON file, and expect anything to happen automagically. You need to post the data to a server-side script. Seeing your code at the beginning of the PHP file, that's presumably the address you want to post to. But you'll want to do the opposite of Kenny's answer, because if you use GET, your script will write to the file on _every_ request, so when you call the page already. Use POST instead, and look into isset/empty to first of all _properly check_ if the parameters your script expects actually exist.

Answer (score 1):

You use POST method to send AJAX request, but try to get it by using GET method from PHP.

Simply change AJAX method from POST to GET can solve the problem.

Comment: I made a change from "POST" to "GET" in the AJAX but it still doesn't work and it gives me an error in the console: http://prntscr.com/eileli

Comment: Try to move the whole <script> section into the <head> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an AJAX request directly to `light.json` instead of PHP page. Moreover you're using `type: "POST"` on AJAX but reading from `$_GET` on PHP.

If the PHP script is on the same page, you won't need to specify `url` in your AJAX request

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['light'])) {
    $light = $_GET['light'];
    $file = fopen("light.json", "w") or die("can't open file");
    if($light == "on") {  
        fwrite($file, '{"light": "on"}');
    } else if ($light == "off") {  
        fwrite($file, '{"light": "off"}');
    }
    echo fread($file, filesize($file));
}
?>

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: {"light": "on"},
    success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
    },
    error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
    }
    });
```

Be sure that `light.json` is in the same directory, otherwise specify the correct path on `fopen()`.

Comment: @ExPoNe seems that `tunOn` function is not defined in your code.